# Is there a way to create a dump file of what the Windows Resource Monitor records every second?

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance, performance-monitor

Or basically, archive all activity of all tasks across a span of 1 hour?

What about all activity of a particular task?

And is there also a way to create a similar dump file for activity recorded on Task Manager?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Performance Monitor. Under Data Set Collectors select System then System Performance.

It will write, once a second, to a log file under `c:\perflogs` until you tell it to stop or it runs out of disk space.