# How to get Windows resource monitor data in realtime for export?

Tags: windows, command-line, resource-monitor

Resource Monitor allows us to see memory usage and other stats, is there any API which can be accessed by command line to play with the data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/331990/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-dump-file-of-what-the-windows-resource-monitor-record

Comment: No, similar in one way but API gives real time exposure while dump is like one time export/snapshot

Answer (score 1):

The Resource Monitor gets its data from the Windows
[Performance Counters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/performance-counters-portal).

You can use the free utility
[pslist](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pslist)
for accessing these counters.

You could also use the pseudo-registry key `HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA` for
getting these values.
The HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA hive can be accessed locally through standard registry API functions or
[Microsoft RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_RPC)
(MSRPC).
It's a virtual registry hive, so cannot be seen in `regedit`,
and it's also real-time.

This area is very badly documented, so I cannot supply a good link.
You will need to search for the information you will need.

See for example one article where this is demonstrated using PowerShell
[Using PowerShell to Aid in Security Forensics](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-using-powershell-to-aid-in-security-forensics/).